# Symfony - extension able to load the configuration

Tags: php, bundle, symfony4, fosuserbundle

I am trying to install [FOSUserBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/command_line_tools.html) based on a documentation.

I have created fos_user.yaml file in conifig/packages path with:

```
fos_user:
db_driver: orm
firewall_name: main
user_class: bundles\App\Base\Entity\User
from_email:
    address: "my@mail.com"
    sender_name: "Name Surname"
framework:
    translator: ~
```

But it keeps throwing error:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "from_email" (in /
>   !!    var/www/html/config/packages/fos_user.yaml). Looked for namespace "from_ema
>   !!    il", found "framework", "sensio_framework_extra", "doctrine_cache", "doctri
>   !!    ne", "doctrine_migrations", "maker", "security", "swiftmailer", "stof_doctr
>   !!    ine_extensions", "doctrine_fixtures", "twig", "twig_extra", "fos_user"

I tried of making from_email.yaml but it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration that you provided in your `fos_user.yaml` file isn't well indented.

If you don't indent the values under the `fos_user` key, Symfony will try to find a configuration file for each of them.

You should write instead :

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: bundles\App\Base\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "my@mail.com"
        sender_name: "Name Surname"
```

For more details, you can see the full bundle configuration [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/configuration_reference.html)

Comment: Thank you. This did it. :) @Manu